# Backgroundworker CancelAsync() won't work

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am trying to cancel my Backgroundworker with `WorkerClass.bw.CancelAsync()`. But it wont work at all.

**//edit! I posted the full Code here. May this will help.
Okay, i added some Msgboxes to know if the Worker is still busy and the wired thing is, that i get a `false` while the worker is doing things!?!?**

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btn_start_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_start.Click
        Dim WorkerClass As New BGWClass
        WorkerClass.bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        WorkerClass.bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        If btn_start.Text = "Start" Then
            btn_start.Image = My.Resources.Resources.gem_remove
            btn_add_addy.Enabled = False
            btn_start.Text = "Stop"
            WorkerClass.Start()
            WorkerClass.bw.RunWorkerAsync()
            MsgBox(WorkerClass.bw.IsBusy & " " & WorkerClass.bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        Else
            btn_start.Image = My.Resources.Resources.error_fuck
            btn_add_addy.Enabled = True
            btn_start.Enabled = False
            MsgBox(WorkerClass.bw.IsBusy & " " & WorkerClass.bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
            WorkerClass.bw.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class BGWClass
    Public bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    Sub Start()
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
         For x As Integer = 1 To 15
            If bw.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
            bw.ReportProgress(x)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Dim myObject As Object = e.UserState
        Form1.Prgs_error.Text = "- Error: " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        '...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you set `WorkerClass.bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True`? Otherwise it won't cancel anything.

Comment: Could you put the entire backgroundworker code please ?

Comment: I did. Could you please look over it again =)?

Comment: Allready added the part. The cancellation check isnt the problem. It works fine. My problem is, that the worker is telling me it isnt busy?

Comment: Can you put in a in your button click handler and confirm that `CancelAsync` is even being called?

Comment: Oh damn. I'am such an idi... thats it. Can't imagine how stupid I'am. Sometimes the easiest things are the mistakes :)

Thanks Mike!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes to see the things sitting right in front of us :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are only evaluating `CancellationPending` once, at the start of your `bw_DoWork` method. Since there's not really a way to cancel the `BackgroundWorker` before it starts, `CancellationPending` will always be false and will never interrupt the work.  The BackgroundWorker doesn't use some magic to take over the program counter when you call `CancelAsync`.

In order for this to work, the core logic of your `DoWork` method will have to be implemented in a way that allows for the frequent polling of `CancellationPending` so that the code will know exactly when to exit out of what it's doing.  You will need to go from this:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, 
                      ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        'do stuff here
    End If

End Sub
```

To something more like this:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, 
                      ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim workIsCompleted As Boolean = False
    While (Not bw.CancellationPending) AndAlso (Not workIsCompleted) Then

        ' Do stuff here, but incrementally so that the while loop can
        ' periodically check to see if CancelAsync has been called.
        ' Also, be sure to set workIsCompleted = True when the work is done.
        ' Otherwise, you will just spin forever until someone cancels it
        ' (Which may or may not be a bad thing, depending on your requirements)

    End While

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the basic model of a BackgroundWorker.  Is this how yours look.

```
Dim WithEvents worker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'start
    If Not worker.IsBusy Then
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'cancel
    If worker.IsBusy AndAlso worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
        worker.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub foo_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
    For x As Integer = 1 To 15
        If worker.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
        worker.ReportProgress(x)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub foo_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles worker.ProgressChanged
    Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub foo_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles worker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        Label1.Text = "canceled"
    ElseIf Not IsNothing(e.Error) Then
        Label1.Text = "error " & e.Error.Message
    Else
        Label1.Text = "done"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not exactly, but mostoly this should be the same as my code. All works  espect the `CancelAsync()`

Comment: Okay, i tried to edit mine with yours and i allways get the boolean false for `worker.IsBusy`. Don't know why, cause the worker is working?!

Comment: There is probably a delay from the time you call RunWorkerAsync before the background worker actually starts and updates the property to `True`.  It takes time to spawn a new thread and start executing the code.  Your next line where you check `IsBusy` (again, once and only once) probably happens before any of that completes.  If you put in some arbitrary delay (say 3000 ms) then it would probably work.

Comment: Okay, u'r right. But this still didn't solve my problem. I still cant cancel the worker at all. Even with a simply `For Next Statement`

Answer (score 0):

create:
1 x form called "Form1",

containing
1 x button called "Button1",
1 x progressbar called "ProgressBar1".

Then paste this code in:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

' Create a BackgroundWorker instance
Private WithEvents backgroundWorker1 As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker()


Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Configure the BackgroundWorker
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Set the ProgressBar properties
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100
    progressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub


' Event handler for the Start button click
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Cancel the BackgroundWorker if it's running
    If backgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    Else
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Button1.Text = "Cancel"
    End If
End Sub


' Event handler for the BackgroundWorker's DoWork event
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        ' Check if cancellation is requested
        If backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        ' Simulate work by sleeping for a short duration
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)

        ' Report progress to the UI thread
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
    Next
End Sub


' Event handler for the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged event
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ' Update the ProgressBar value based on the reported progress
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub


' Event handler for the BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' Perform any cleanup or post-processing after the backgroundWorker has either finished, or aborted

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Progress completed!")
        Button1.Text = "Start"
        'ProgressBar1.Value = 0 ' uncomment this is you want it to reset after a completion as well
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Aborted!")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Button1.Text = "Start"
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: The single button alternates between a "start" and "cancel" depending whether the backgroundWorker is busy or not